# Core Data exception thrown after migration

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, migration

I'm getting the following exception after migrating Core Data:

[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x544d550

This only happen after migrating and when I click the home button and the app goes to the background.

The instance 0x544d550 is the persistenceStoreCoordinator itself.

Any ideas on what is sending the message?

Thanks!

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint and post the stack trace you receive when the program stops on the exception throw.

Comment: Im getting the same issue.
Please update if youve solved it.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator retain]` you're calling an object method (those methods that start with a `-` (minus) on a class. Retain should be called in objects.

You should first create the object (allocate) and then retain it (if needed).

Here's an example of how to use that class:

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* persistentStoreCoordinator = 
[[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]];
```

Note that objects created that way already have a reference count of `1` (one). You'd need to RELEASE it once you're done with it. Unless you're using iOS 5 with ARC, wich you should not mess with the number of references, since the garbage collector will take care of that for you.

EDIT:
I just realised that that's the ERROR message, and not your actual code.

If you're getting the message that you can't retain an unallocated object, you're probably doing something like this:

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* persistentStoreCoordinator;
[persistentStoreCoordinator retain];
```

or

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]];
[persistentStoreCoordinator release];
[persistentStoreCoordinator retain];
```

In which you're retaining an non-allocated object, wich should be the reason of the message you're getting.